# Wrong number of digits in format.pval()?

Tags: r, digits, p-value

When specifying 3 digits in `format.pval()`, why does, say, `0.019950` outputs 4 digits:

```
format.pval(0.019950, eps=.001, digits=3, nsmall=3)
"0.0199"
```

But, say, `0.019951` outputs 3 digits:

```
format.pval(0.019951, eps=.001, digits=3, nsmall=3)
"0.020"
```

## Edit (Solution):

The solution to having 3 digits while preserving the *p*-value formatting, based on `dcarlson's` answer, was simply to round the value to 3 digits before passing it to `format.pval()`:

```
format.pval(round(0.019950, digits=3), eps=.001, digits=3, nsmall=3)
"0.020"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `digits=` argument here and elsewhere in R is SIGNIFICANT digits, not decimal digits. Significant digits ignore leading 0's in a decimal so the first response is 3 significant digits since you do not count the 0 following the decimal point. In the second example the answer is rounded up to .02, but nsmall=3 forces the additional trailing 0.

In addition, specifying a `digits=` argument in R is usually treated as advisory so it may not be followed. You can always force R to print the number of decimals using `round` or the formatting function `sprintf`.

```
format.pval(round(0.019950, 3), digits=3, nsmall=3)
# [1] "0.020"
sprintf("%.3f", .019950)
# [1] "0.020"
```

Comment: IMO the critical issue of the main post is the combination of `digits` and `nsmall`. Not really sure how this is substantially different from my earlier answer (other than you explaining what a significant digits is).

Comment: And providing two ways to get exactly the number of decimal digits desired.

Comment: Not true. I was working on the answer before your comment or answer.  Feel free to look at my other posts, answers.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for providing useful answers—I've upvoted both. I'd like to accept both answers, but I've [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers) "pick the answer that was most useful/helpful to you. This may differ from the criteria you laid out when asking the question." Accepting Maurits's answer would probably require the extra steps of asking him to modify his answer to include the `sprintf` solution (and edit my question accordingly), so I've accepted dcarlson's answer. Or is it fine to accept both answers?

Answer (score 2):

To address your first question *"why does, say, 0.019950 outputs 4 digits"*: With the argument `digits = 3` you specify that you'd like to show the first 3 *significant* digits after the decimal point (which are `199`). From `?format.pval`

> digits: how many significant digits are to be used.

In response to your second question: `0.019951` with `digits = 3` first gets rounded to `"0.02"` (you can confirm that by looking at the output of `format.pval(0.019951, eps=.001, digits=3)`). Then by setting `nsmall = 3` you ask for 3 digits after the decimal point, which turns `"0.02"` into `"0.020"`.

Comment: Great. I'll accept your answer, but if I'd like to always have 3 digits, would you recommend that I open a new question or edit this one?

Comment: @RemPsyc What do you mean by *"always have 3 digits"*: 3 *significant* digits or 3 digits *after the decimal point*? To always have 3 digits after the decimal point, I'd recommend using `sprintf`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant always 3 digits after the decimal point (NOT 3 "significant" digits).

Comment: @RemPsyc In that case, use `sprintf("%.3f", c(0.019951, 0.019950))`